# Elasticsearch - Geocode (Postgres data)

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, geocoding, sql-view

I am new in Elasticsearch, but I read that is one of the best solutions for offline geocoding. Currently I have prepared data in PostgreSQL database with sql view which has these columns:

- country
- city
- street
- house number
- post code
- lat
- lon

How should I proceed to work with this data into ElasticSearch and will able full text search with ignoring diacritics? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Geo point: look at:
[Geo point](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html)

Text search look at:
[Text search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/full-text-queries.html)